# How to access a class data member from a method withing same class

Tags: javascript, class, methods, event-handling

I have a class and it has a constructor.
I assign a class variable by `this.something` and it is not being accessed in some another function inside the same class.

Following is my class

```
class A {
    some_func() {
        console.log(this.var1);  // this is giving undefined
    }
    constructor(socket, var1) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.var1 = var1;

        this.socket.on('some event', some_func);
    }
}
```

Inside the `some_func` function the variable is undefined. 
How do i fix that?

Comment: Do a `console.log(this);` inside `some_func()`. Check if that actually refers to class a or socket. You might need to call it like `some_func.bind(this)`

Comment: When you assign a function your `this` context doesn't get automatically attached to the function invocation,.. To get around this you can do -> `this.some_func.bind(this)`

Comment: @palash Right! the `bind()` method did the job! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with your code. Are you definitely instantiating the variable before using the method? As shown below

```js
class A {

    constructor(socket, var1) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.var1 = var1;

        //this.socket.on('some event', this.some_func);
    }
    
    some_func() {
        console.log(this.var1);  // this is giving undefined
    }
}

var instanceA = new A('socket', 'var')

instanceA.some_func() // Returns 'var'
```

Comment: `I don't see a problem ` because your not doing the same thing, change the `this.socket.on`, to a simple `setTimeout` and you will get the same problem.

Comment: make sure you're refering to this.some_func not some_func

Comment: That is not what i wanted. setTimeout wont work for me

Comment: @Shantanu That's not what I'm suggesting, my suggestion was for emulating the problem your seeing.  And why using `bind` as I & palaѕн suggested.